# Loop over a different set of control variables in stata

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I am trying to loop over a different set of control variables. I run the below code but get an error `{ required`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
local tmax "tmax_3 tmax_2 tmax_1 tmax0 tmax1 tmax2 tmax3"
local tmin "tmin_3 tmin_2 tmin_1 tmin0 tmin1 tmin2 tmin3"
local precip "precip_3 precip_2 precip_1 precip0 precip1 precip2 precip3"

est clear
local m=1
foreach var of varlist good_health better_health {
    foreach weather of local tmax tmin precip {
        eststo model_`m'_`weather': reg `var' `weather', robust cluster(parish_id)
        local m `++m'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using syntax `of local` in `foreach` Stata expects only one local. So after the first local Stata expects a `{`. But you have a second and a third local before the `{`. You should be able to solve this using `in` in `foreach` where Stata first interprets your three locals, then iterate over all items in each of them. See below.

```
local tmax "tmax_3 tmax_2 tmax_1 tmax0 tmax1 tmax2 tmax3"
local tmin "tmin_3 tmin_2 tmin_1 tmin0 tmin1 tmin2 tmin3"
local precip "precip_3 precip_2 precip_1 precip0 precip1 precip2 precip3"

est clear
local m=1
foreach var of varlist good_health better_health {
    foreach weather in tmax tmin precip {
        eststo model_`m'_`weather': reg `var' ``weather'', robust cluster(parish_id)
        local m `++m'
    }
}
```

Edit: Now you are only iterating over the names of the local. ``` ``weather'' ``` is now a nested local, where it first gets the name that the local `weather' points to, then it interprets that local and gets your variable list.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The code run but it does not show the desired output. It loops over each of the variables within each local. Instead I would like it to loop over the three locas as one set. I would likesix regressions (2 independent variables x3 sets of controls), instead of 2 x 3 x 6. In other words, these are the six regression: `reg good_health $tmax`, `reg good_health $tmin`, `reg good_health $precip`, `reg better_health $tmax`, `reg better_health $tmin`, `reg better_health $precip`

Comment: Perhaps, I should have used global macros instead of locals.

Comment: I have made an edit to my answer